# JQueryUI Datepicker - how to hi-light days before/after selected date on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/K5upK/

I've been trying to figure out how to hi-light all days before/after a selected date but I can't seem to get the background colors for the table cells to change while hovering.  The effect I'm looking for is similar to the hovering functionality on www.kayak.com.  What I have working so far lets a user select a start/end date and it hi-lights all days between with a light blue color.  What am I forgetting to do?  Here's the code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'></link>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'>

    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="datepicker">
        Dates:
        <label><b>To:</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="input1" size="10">
            <label><b>From:</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="input2" size="10">

    </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: false,
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths: 2,

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            var className;


            if (startDate && (date.getTime() == startDate.getTime())) {
                className = "start-date"
            }
            else if (endDate && (date.getTime() == endDate.getTime())) {
                className = "end-date";
            }
            else if ((startDate && endDate) && (startDate < date && date < endDate)) {
                className = "between-date";
            }
            else {
                className = "";
            }

            return [true, className];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);


            if (!startDate || endDate) {
                $("#input1").val(dateText);
                $("#input2").val("");
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else if( selectedDate < startDate ) {
                $("#input2").val( $("#input1").val() );
                $("#input1").val( dateText );
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else {
                $("#input2").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker();
            }
        }
    });

    $('.datepicker').on('mouseenter', 'td a', function() {
        console.log('in mouseenter');
        var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
        var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());

        if (startDate) {
            var cell = $(this);
            cell.addClass('between-date');            
            console.log(cell);
        }

    })
});
```

main.css

```
.start-date .ui-state-default, .end-date .ui-state-default {
    background: #0000FF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.between-date .ui-state-default {
    background: #9999FF;
}
```

Comment: if you can create a working Jsfiddle, will be eaiser to help.

Comment: I can see the effect on kayak.com, it seems like you got it, you want to change highlight on hover, or before and after days?, to change highlight on hover, just override the ui css, property is:'.ui-datepicker td:hover' , before and after days are the oppisite of what you have done, actually with a beautiful writing code.

Comment: Right so I want the days between where my mouse currently is and the start date to be hi-lighted.  For example, if the date picker is currently displaying Jan/Feb and I select [Jan 9th, 2014] as my start date and I hover my mouse over to [February 1, 2014], I need all the dates between Jan 9 and Feb 1 to be highlighted with the 'between-date' CSS.  I'm trying to override mouse enter but I can't seem to get the logic right.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing but in the example above the highlight only occur after picking two dates. I wanted the highlight to appear on all between dates directly after selecting the first date and hovering any other dates. I modified your jsfiddle and this is my solution to get the hover to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/K5upK/32/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: false,
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
        var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
        var className;

        if (startDate && (date.getTime() == startDate.getTime())) {
            className = "start-date"
        }
        else if (endDate && (date.getTime() == endDate.getTime())) {
            className = "end-date";
        }
        else if ((startDate && endDate) && (startDate < date && date < endDate)) {
            className = "between-date";
        }
        else {
            className = "";
        }

        return [true, className];
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
        var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
        var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

        if (!startDate || endDate) {
            $("#input1").val(dateText);
            $("#input2").val("");
            $(this).datepicker();
        } else if( selectedDate < startDate ) {
            $("#input2").val( $("#input1").val() );
            $("#input1").val( dateText );
            $(this).datepicker();
        } else {
            $("#input2").val(dateText);
            $(this).datepicker();
        }
    }
});

$('.datepicker').on('mouseenter', 'td a', function() {
    $(".between-date").removeClass("between-date"); // reset
    isBetween = false;
    foundFirst = 0;
    calendar = $(this).closest('.ui-datepicker');
    if(calendar.find('.start-date').length > 0 && calendar.find('.end-date').length == 0) {
        calendar.find('.ui-state-default').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("ui-state-active")) {
                if(foundFirst==0) foundFirst=-1;
                isBetween = (foundFirst == -1 ? true : false);
            }
            if($(this).hasClass("ui-state-hover")) {
                if(foundFirst==0) foundFirst=1;
                isBetween = (foundFirst == 1 ? true : false);
            }
            if(isBetween) {
                $(this).addClass("between-date");
            } 
        });
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I did this to highlight specific days in a range...

```
function loadDatepickers(){
   var fromDate = new Date($(".lblDateFrom").text());
   var toDate = new Date($(".lblDateTo").text());

   ....
   },
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
     if (date >= fromDate && date <= toDate) {
       return [true, 'ui-individual-date', '']; //css class that applies the highlighting to each date
     }
     else {
       return [true, '', ''];
     }
   }),

....
// in css file
.ui-individual-date {
background-color: #F2F5F7;
```

}

Comment: I also did this to add :hover to each date:  .ui-datepicker table td:hover {
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}